# Error while deleting all child controls from the parent control

Tags: c#, asp.net, parent-child

I have the next aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="newsEditor.aspx.cs" Inherits="ExpertSiteV2.newsEditor" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="ExpertSiteV2" Namespace="ExpertSiteV2" TagPrefix="custom" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Width="660" Style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Width="150">Заголовок новости</asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="newsTitle" runat="server" Width="500" Style="float: right;"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:Panel>
        <custom:CustomEditor ID="Editor3" runat="server" Height="300" Width="660" BackColor="White" />
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Style="margin-top: 5px;" CssClass="buttonPanel">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="SaveImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="img/save_32.png"
                ToolTip="Сохранить новость" />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="SaveLinkButton1" runat="server" ToolTip="Сохранить новость">Сохранить</asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" ImageUrl="img/block_32.png"
                PostBackUrl="news.aspx" ToolTip="Вернуться к странице новостей" />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" ToolTip="Вернуться к странице новостей"
                CausesValidation="False" PostBackUrl="news.aspx">Отмена</asp:LinkButton>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Заголовок должен быть заполнен!"
            ControlToValidate="newsTitle" Display="Dynamic">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

I want to delete all the contents of `Panel1`. I write the code:

```
Panel1.Controls.Clear();
```

But it doesn't work and I get the message:

> Page cannot be null. Please ensure
>   that this operation is being performed
>   in the context of an ASP.NET request.
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Page
>   cannot be null. Please ensure that
>   this operation is being performed in
>   the context of an ASP.NET request.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Page
>   cannot be null. Please ensure that
>   this operation is being performed in
>   the context of an ASP.NET request.]
>   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.get_IPage()
>   +373832    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +54
>   System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs
>   e) +8698462
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1029
>
> Blockquote

What's wrong? How should I do it properly?

Comment: Have you tried the same with Panel2 just to make sure the call works?  If the call works, then what I think it means is that not only does it kill the child controls, but the main control (itself) as well.  However, I wouldn't think it would do that, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, other panels (panel2, panel3) remove all their childs (but not  itself). It's good.
But Panel1 doesn't want to delete child controls (even if it is contained in other panel or it has neighbour panels so the content is not empty)

Comment: I think the problem is in the child controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i've written something like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="newsEditor.aspx.cs" Inherits="ExpertSiteV2.newsEditor" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="ExpertSiteV2" Namespace="ExpertSiteV2" TagPrefix="custom" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Width="660" Style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Width="150">Заголовок новости</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="newsTitle" runat="server" Width="500" Style="float: right;"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:Panel>
            <custom:CustomEditor ID="Editor3" runat="server" Height="300" Width="660" BackColor="White" />
            <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Style="margin-top: 5px;" CssClass="buttonPanel">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="SaveImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="img/save_32.png"
                    ToolTip="Сохранить новость" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="SaveLinkButton1" runat="server" ToolTip="Сохранить новость">Сохранить</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" ImageUrl="img/block_32.png"
                    PostBackUrl="news.aspx" ToolTip="Вернуться к странице новостей" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" ToolTip="Вернуться к странице новостей"
                    CausesValidation="False" PostBackUrl="news.aspx">Отмена</asp:LinkButton>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Заголовок должен быть заполнен!"
                ControlToValidate="newsTitle" Display="Dynamic">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is one more panel that contains everything. And I've written:

```
Panel4.Controls.Clear();
```

It works fine.
I still don't know why the Panel1 doesn't want to remove child controls. If someone knows just write the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you not just hide the panel? Panel1.Visible = false. why do you wanna remove the controls.

Aha ok I get the question now:
Check out this project, http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/DynamicUC.aspx

Comment: But i want nobody to get access to this elements through the source code of the html page.